# Datatables regex search for exact string (not the substring)

Tags: jquery, regex, datatables, datatables-1.10

Let's say i have a table with three rows. In one column, i have these vaules

1. coach
2. Assistant Coach
3. Coach assistant coach
4. Coach

If i do a search now for "coach", all rows return. I don't want that. What I need is two sets of code to do the following operations:

1) to be able to type the word "coach" and only have it return rows 1 and 3.
2) to be able to type the word "coach" and only have it return row 1 (case sensitive)

In other words, I don't want any records returned that have the substring coach. Just coach. I haven't been able to figure this out as there is a space between assistant and coach and the regex i have recognizes the free standing word and returns it.

Let me know if this is possible.

My current code is:

```
var stringFilter = $(this).val();          
var myregex = ("\\b" + stringFilter + "\\b");
$("##add_grid").DataTable().column().columns(7).search(myregex,true,false).draw();
```

Comment: Can you try if ($("#add_grid").DataTable().column().columns(7).search("\"" + myregex + "\"",true,false)) >= 0) { $("#add_grid").DataTable().column().columns(7).search("\"" + myregex + "\"",true,false).draw(); }

Comment: You might have better luck asking a question about the regex and not datatables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want search by exact string you can use [column().search()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()) try this code:

```
dt.column(0).search("^" + "coach" + "$", true, true, false).draw();
```

**Result:** https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/87/

Comment: I think I should begin checking existing answers before wasting time only ro produdce an answer already there :) http://jsfiddle.net/q800bevm/

Comment: Why i modifier is not working in this sample? https://jsfiddle.net/7kfmyw6x/1059/

Comment: @MiguelFebres remove  '/' and 'i' from your example check: https://jsfiddle.net/7kfmyw6x/1063/

Comment: @CMedina the problem was with laraval datatables library. It's working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff, try the following code:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
table.column().columns(6).search(myregex,true,false).draw();
} );
```

Remember that columns starts in 0. Check if your column is in the position #7. Hope this helps!

Comment: I know about the column indexes. I don't see how your code is any different than what I wrote outside of changing the column index.

Comment: Jeff, are you working with client side or server side?

Comment: Jeff, this may help you: http://howtolearncode.com/question/12561323-datatables-individual-column-filtering-select-tag-use-exact-match

Answer (score 0):

data table provide more flexibility. to work with table data please find below it will help:

```js
/*column().search( input [,regex[ , smart[ , caseInsen ]]] ) */

 $("#add_grid").DataTable().column(i).search($('#col' + i + '_filter').val(), true,true,false).draw();
```